# Erro ao fazer o parser de um retorno de uma requisição SOAP usando curl no PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap, parser

Olá estou fazendo um solicitação CURL em que passo um envelope XML, estou fazendo via CURL porque ocorre um erro quando uso o SoapClient então achei que essa solicitação vila CURL me atende, mas é retornado um outro XML e ao tentar efetuar o parse desse XML não exibe nada apenas se pedir para exibir em XML mesmo, alguém poderia me ajudar nessa questão?

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <S:Body>
                <ns2:verificarSituacaoCondutorResponse xmlns:ns2="http://sistemasExternos.refor.com.br/">
                    <return><?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> <pessoa> <registro>05417160432</registro> <descricao>Verifique se Condutor pertence a UF do DETRAN</descricao> <retorno>999</retorno> </pessoa> </return>
                </ns2:verificarSituacaoCondutorResponse>
            </S:Body>
        </S:Envelope>
```

Comment: Boas-vindas. Para continuarmos dentro da [finalidade do site](/help) é importante você [edit] a pergunta e fornecer o [mcve] do problema, de forma a facilitar a identificação e servir como referência para futuros visitantes. *Agradecemos a compreensão*.